# How do I get the highest currently used ID number in a table with LINQ?

Tags: database, linq

I have a table with a list of names.  This table has an ID column that is an autoincremented number. I would like to display on my website something like,

"6,523,213 names created so far."

So, I need to get the highest currently index/ID number from my names table.

I can think of a few ways to do it, I could OrderBy ID by desc and select the first one.  But this might not be the fastest way to do this.  I could also stick a field some place and increment it every time I insert a new name into the database.

Is there any easier/fast LINQ express to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use either the COUNT or MAX methods of LINQ:

Assumming a DataContext of that name and an entity named "Names" with a primary key called "Id". Either of these would work:

```
DataContext db = new DataContext();
var nameCount = db.Names.Count();

var nameCount = db.Names.Select(n => n.Id).Max();
```

Comment: Jose - you do not need the Select, you can simply call Max with a selector eg var nameCount = db.Names.Max(n => n.Id);

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want to do is *count the rows* - not get the highest index. Consider what happens when a record is deleted - the number of registered names decreases by one, but the highest index does not...

In plain SQL, you could use this:

```
 SELECT COUNT(ColumnName) FROM TableName
```

If you really want to do it with LINQ, I think [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb737922.aspx#countsimp) will work.